# How do I allow access to HangFire Dashboard outside of localhost with basic user login and password?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am trying to allow access to HangFire Dashboard from any location. I have added the following code:

```cs
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new[]
    {
        new BasicAuthAuthorizationFilter(new BasicAuthAuthorizationFilterOptions
        {
            RequireSsl = false,
            SslRedirect = false,
            LoginCaseSensitive = false,
            Users = new[]
            {
                new BasicAuthAuthorizationUser
                {
                    Login = "admin",
                    PasswordClear = "test",
                },
            },
        }),
    },
    IsReadOnlyFunc = (DashboardContext context) => true,
});
```

But I am getting an error:
`Error CS7069 Reference to type 'IAuthorizationFilter' claims it is defined in 'Hangfire.Core', but it could not be found`

How can I configure the dashboard with simple user access?

Comment: Which package are you using for dashboard authorization?

Comment: @ctyar I have tried Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization`is only compatible with .NET Framework.
For .NET Core you should use [Hangfire.Dashboard.BasicAuthorization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire.Dashboard.BasicAuthorization)
It only supports the basic authorization, but your piece of code will work as is.

Comment: Thank you, that package seems to do the trick. Is there any chance that you might now how can I use a proxy with this? I have a blazor + webapi app on my server, only blazor has access from the outside, but hangfire is inside webapi. I tried using proxy to display hangfire dashboard via blazor app, it works on my machine, but when I put in on a server, I am getting a "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: @TK-421 I think it's better to open a new question and post how you are proxying the call, it's hard to answer without seeing the code