# Hangfire authorization packages not compatible with .net7

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

Am facing a problem in authorization packages in .net7.
Actually the package hangfire.authorization its last version is not compatible with .net7 and i need to add a basic authentication and authorization to my dashboard.
Any solution for this please.

I tried to create custom filter but i didnt succeed to make it work.
I expect a solution that helps me to add auth to my dash or if there are any new packages for hangfire in .net7 that do this.

Comment: Taken a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76835681/7450780)?